# Mostrar fechas con el intervalo de edad correspondiente

Tags: sql, oracle

Debo mostrar las edades de nacimiento de una columna `(f_nacimiento)` según un rango de edad `(ciclo_vital)` que ya esta predefinido en una columna.

He intentado obtener la edad por medio de:

```
SELECT F_NACIMIENTO, DATEDIFF(YEAR, F_NACIMIENTO, GETDATE()) AS AÑOS FROM JUAND;
```

Pero me genera un error de *identificador no valido de datediff*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones `DATEDIFF()` y `GETDATE()` no están disponibles en Oracle.

En su lugar puedes hacer uso de [`MONTHS_BETWEEN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm) y [`SYSDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm) como te muestro a continuación:

```
SELECT
  FLOOR(
    MONTHS_BETWEEN(
      SYSDATE,
      F_NACIMIENTO
    ) / 12
  ) edad
FROM JUAND
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en línea en el siguiente enlace:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1745c/1